# How should bug tracking and help tickets integrate?

Tags: process, bug-tracking, issue-tracking

I have a *little* experience with bug tracking systems such as FogBugz where help tickets are issues are (or can be) bugs, and I have some experience using a bug tracking system internally completely separate from a help center system.

My question is, in a company with an existing (home-grown) help center system where replacing it is not an option, how should a bug tracking system (probably Mantis) be integrated into the process?

Right now help tickets get put in for issues, questions, etc and they get assigned to the appropriate person (PC Tech, Help Desk staff, or if it's an application issue they can't solve in the help desk it gets assigned to a developer). A user can put a request for small modifications or fixes to an application in a help ticket and the developer it gets assigned to will make the change at some point, apply their time to that ticket, and then close the ticket when it goes to production.

We don't currently have a bug tracking system, so I'm looking into the best way to integrate one. Should we just take the help tickets and put it into the bug tracking system if it's a bug (or issue or feature request) and then close the ticket if it's not an emergency fix? We probably don't want to expose the bug tracking system to anyone else as they wouldn't know what to put in the help center system and what to put in the bug tracker... right?

Any thoughts? Suggestions? Tips? Advice? To-dos? Not to-dos? etc...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this for a production system with end users reporting bugs, or for issue resolution during QA?

If it is the former, some live person should triage the help desk tickets and only log as a bug what really is one.

If it is the latter, you should not integrate at all.

Comment: It need to be for tracking bugs... both those we find internally and the ones end users find... both before and after applications are in production.

Comment: Ok, I think my answer still applies.

Comment: So basically don't integrate them just have someone that "converts" help tickets to issues when appropriate? Obviously could integrate so the person can do that automatically with a button click...

Comment: Yes, that's how we do it as well. One advantage of web-based systems in this case is that even without explicit support for integration, you can just put links to the other system into text fields :-).

Answer (score 3):

Have a promote to bug button on the help desk system, that publish the ticket on the bug tracker, with the appropiate reference info.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's a tradeoff.

We use separate systems for help desk tickets and for bugs.

Pros:

- Workflows & requirements will probably different between devs and help desk, you can choose a system for each that fits requirements (e.g. fields that are only relevant for dev or for help desk, different kinds of email integration).
- Clear responsibilities: Help desk handles tickets, devs handle Bugs.

Cons:

- Integration will not be quite seamless (you need either automatic integration, which does not always exist, or manual back-forth links, which people may forget).

So far, we're quite happy with two products. It is occasionally annoying to have to paste links or close a ticket and a bug, but usually tickets and bugs are handled by different people anyway, so it's not a big deal.

One product might also work well, if you can find one which fits everyone's workflow.

Answer (score 0):

In the **raiseaticket help-desk system**, we create a separate workflow for Prod, Dev and Bugs. The ticket is assigned to relevant group based on the nature of the issue. These tickets are not exposed to any other group. So, we can do a workaround in our help-desk portal system for the bug tracking.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone in 2022 (and beyond) looking to integrate a help desk system and bug tracker, DoneDone does this well.

We use a DoneDone *mailbox* for general customer support (both via our support email address and the contact form on our website). It lets you have private discussion on emails, along with allowing you to assign, prioritize, tag, and create/change statuses on them (e.g. "Open", "In Progress", etc.)

We use DoneDone *projects* to manage internal bugs/issues/tasks.

DoneDone lets you [connect support emails (the helpdesk part) to internal tasks (the bug tracking part) as well](https://www.donedone.com/blog/new-create-link-tasks-directly-from-your-mailbox-conversations). So, if your company has distinct support and client-facing people while also having internal devs and you want to separate their work, you can create any number of subtasks from an incoming conversation.

Even if your company isn't that stratified, it's nice to be able to create bugs with their own workflows separate from a helpdesk ticket (which has its own workflow).

More info at https://www.donedone.com